# How can I cut the margin of a PDF or djvu file for optimal booklet printing?

Tags: pdf, file-format, format-conversion, djvu

I have a file which has exaggerated margins. This forces me to print it as a booklet, otherwise I feel I'm waisting paper (a good size of the font allows me to do so). But if I print directly in booklet format I still get those large margins.

*How can I get rid of them? can I create a new file in which those margins do not appear and print it optimally as a booklet?*

Comment: Can you share with us a page of that booklet? One page should be enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorite tool to **crop PDF files** is [BRISS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) java program available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/

Comment: +1! While it's not my favourite program to work with due to its Java nature, it does the job really well. It was the only one capable of cropping an eBook with different page sizes throughout the document really well.

Comment: Doesn't work. The 'preview' window just gives me a blank white square I have to blindly draw a crop region on and see if it's anywhere near where I need it when the file is saved.

Comment: I can confirm this. No surprise, because it hasn't been updated since 2012. :-(

Answer (score 8):

Try `pdfcrop`, available on the package `texlive-extra-utils`.

```
pdfcrop --margins 0 file.pdf
```

This will take the original PDF and crop completely the margins of it, assuming it is generated will real margins. If you want some margins, you can change the 0 for another number like 5 or 10.

Comment: This doesn't work for PDFs with margins not marked as such. Practically: not working at all (imo).

Answer (score 3):

I use either Briss as in Sadi's answer, or [pdf scissors](http://www.pdfscissors.com/).

If your file is made of scanned images, you may want an even better (but more time consuming) option: [Scan tailor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/scantailor/). It is available from the software center.

This software works with scanned books to produce high quality images which you may transform into a pdf by using `pdftk` or other programs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the freeware [PDF Scissors](http://www.PDFScissors.com), which automates the process of cutting the white margins off PDF pages in a PDF document.

If you plan to crop out or cut out your desired portion from your PDF document, try [PDF Copy Paste](http://www.pdfcopypaste.com). It's a feature-rich product that serves your purpose as well.